# Mutiple selection select boxes with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using 4 tables to fill a chart, similar to these:

```
@colors             @types                  @fuels
-----------------   ---------------------   -------------------
| ID |  Color   |   | ID |     Type     |   | ID |    Fuel    |
-----------------   ---------------------   -------------------
| 1  | 'Red'    |   | 1  | 'SUV'        |   | 1  | 'Gasoline' |
| 2  | 'Green'  |   | 2  | 'Truck'      |   | 2  | 'Diesel'   |
| 3  | 'Blue'   |   | 3  | 'Sports Car' |   | 3  | 'Electric' |
| 4  | 'Yellow' |   | 4  | 'Compact'    |   | 4  | 'Hybrid'   |
-----------------   ---------------------   -------------------
```

The last table is an orders table, similar to this:

```
@orders
--------------------------------------------------------
| order_id | color_id | type_id | fueld_id | purchases |
--------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |    2     |    1    |    4     |     2     |
|    2     |    1     |    4    |    1     |     4     |
|    3     |    2     |    2    |    2     |     6     |
|    4     |    4     |    1    |    4     |     2     |
|    5     |    1     |    4    |    2     |     1     |
|    6     |    3     |    3    |    3     |     1     |
|    7     |    3     |    3    |    3     |     2     |
|    8     |    2     |    1    |    1     |     2     |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a controller that polls data from them all to make the chart. So far so good. Now, I want to let the user pick one or more attributes from each table, to make a dynamic orders page.

My approach is to show 3 select boxes (listboxes) that could allow the user to make a selection, and based on this, the @orders table would be modified. The modifications would land on different action, say:

```
def newtable
    ...
end
```

I know how to do this via SQL, but I'm not too sure how to properly show these listboxes using RoR. My idea is to pick one, several, or ALL the elements of each table.

Would form_for do the trick? I was trying to use it, but I don't have a model to base the query on, and I'm not sure how to create one (or if that approach is actually viable).

Thanks.

Comment: How are these variables set ? "@colors @types @fuels"

Comment: For the initial view, they have all the records from their respective models. So that'd be: "\@colors = Color.all, @\types = Type.all, @\fuels = Fuel.all". Ughh, sorry, I don't know how to escape the @'s, I had to put additional chars, cause the website thinks I'm trying to refer to a user.

Comment: You said, "Would form_for do the trick? I was trying to use it, but I don't have a model to base the query on,".. Type, Fuel and Color are the models

Comment: Right, but wouldn't that make individual forms for each of them? I need a single form that would gather the data of the 3.

Comment: An 'Order' Form page with the three select boxes for colors,types and fuels.Is this what you want.?

Comment: Yes, an Order form page is what you want. But the associations should be built right. Simple, Order, belongs_to :type,:fuel,:color and purchase

Comment: @Pavan: Yes, that's correct. I don't know exactly what to put in the code.

Comment: @beck03076: I haven't got to do those yet, I'll see to that before I get deeper on this. Could you provide an example if they were correctly built, though?

Comment: Your Order Table contains these fields color_id,type_id,fuel_id?

Comment: Yes, I didn't name them as such (I may have oversimplified them too much), but the Order table does contain the foreign keys of each of the other 3 tables.

Comment: Come here....http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12592/select

Comment: @beck03076 Apparently I need more reputation to use the chat feature, though I just realized your comment was here. An hour later. :/ Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm Not Familiar with Rails 4 yet,but i can provide an answer as  per Rails 3.

First Make Necessary **Associations**.

And In your Orders controller define one new method like

```
def create
----your stuff---
end
```

**In your Order Form page**:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>

<%= collection_select :order,:color_id, @colors,'id','Color',{:label=> 'Select a Color',:prompt=> 'Select'} %>

<%= collection_select :order,:type_id, @types,'id','Type',{:label=> 'Select a Type',:prompt=> 'Select'} %>

<%= collection_select :order,:fuel_id, @fuels,'id','Fuel',{:label=> 'Select a Fuel',:prompt=> 'Select'} %>

<%= submit_tag "Create" %>
```

Hope this works.

**Note:** This is just a sample code for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try when I'm done adjusting the associations.

Comment: I almost got it to work as I want. This does work, but it's a combobox. Is there a way to make it a listbox? So that you can select multiple options? I tried adding ":multiple => true" to the list of attributes, but that didn't do a thing.

Comment: I figured it out, there was another portion of the parameters I was not including. I think this is it. I'll get some hours of sleep and update when I get back here. Thank you.

Comment: @user3209270 Glad you got it!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select(:color, @color.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, 
                                       { :prompt => "Please select"}, 
                                       { :multiple => true, :size => 4 }) %>
```

To configure your controller to accept multiple parameters: [Click Me](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters)

You can create a separate model as a ruby class to handle this if you wish, but only if you find the other models getting too cramped. Hope that helps